# AJAX text property of jQuery control succeeds, returns [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In this script we have a 'stager' function which will act as an intermediary for user interaction on the screen before data are sent back to the database.  The AJAX call succeeds, but instead of the query from the database inside the div, I have [object Object].  If I inspect the console I see that the data coming from the database are correct.  How can I change my code so I can get the text inside my div.  What fundamental element am I misunderstanding with AJAX and JavaScript in general/ tips to avoid this in the future.

EDIT: just noticed that's it's most likely due to the fact that my stageOptions object doesn't have AJAX calls as properties, but straight text.  This is now more in line with what I was trying to get at.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var stageOptions = {
                //some baseline options for the stager control
                size: {
                    small: 'small',
                    medium: 'medium',
                    large: 'large'
                },
                content: {
                    historical: 'historical',
                    predictive: $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../Service.asmx/GetDrugs",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        data.d;
                        console.log(data.d);
                        console.log('success');
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        console.log('error');
                    }
                })
                }
            };
            /*************functions************************/
            function stager(options) {
                var $div = $('<div>').addClass(options.size);
                $div.text(options.content);
                return $div;

            };

            stager({ size: stageOptions.size.small,
                //size and content will be much more variable in the future
                content: stageOptions.content.predictive
            }).appendTo('body');
        });
```

Comment: When you do `alert({foo: "bar"})`, you'll get `[object Object]` too. This is because the string representation of an object is `[object Object]`. If you want to display the json, either change your dataType to text or html, or stringify the json. Or, you can parse the json and create html.

Answer (score 1):

Stringify won't fix this. Setting options.content as the text of your div doesn't work because you're setting the whole content object as the text. I think you also might want to rethink how you're doing this too because you are immediately setting the text of your div and then appending it to the body without checking to see if your ajax request is even done. Normally you'd be able to access your JSON from options.content.responseJSON, but when you set the text the ajax call isn't done and it's still undefined at that point.

You could switch things around to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var stageOptions = {
            //some baseline options for the stager control
            size: {
                small: 'small',
                medium: 'medium',
                large: 'large'
            },
            content: {
                historical: 'historical',
                predictive: 'predictive'
            }
        };
        /*************functions************************/
        function stager(options) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "test.json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var $div = $('<div>').addClass(options.size);
                    $div.text(data.d).appendTo('body');
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    console.log('error');
                }
            });

        };

        stager(stageOptions.size.small);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning an object, so if you want it as a string try:

```
 $div.text(JSON.stringify(options.content));
```